# How can I casting React props.children in TypeScript (tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Now I want to loop each children in props to do something with only some kind of elements

I do like this

```
  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
    if (child.type === MenuItem && child.props.url === path) {
      isActive = true
    }
  })
```

It always warn likes 'type does not exists on type React.ReactElement', 'props does not exists on type React.ReactElement'

But it's works fine but these warning are annoying me, And make me not sure that I did it wrong or not.

Answer (score 2):

you need to define child type/interface

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child:MyReactComponent) => {
  if (child.type === MenuItem && child.props.url === path) {
    isActive = true
  }
})
```

sure u can always use "any" type to skip type checks (and warnings), but u should think before putting "any" type castings everywhere.